# Как реализовать код не используя While?

Tags: javascript

```
while(true){
const carSecSpecif = prompt ('Введите имя первого человека')
    if(!carSecSpecif) break
    
    alert('Это поле не может быть пустым')
}
```

Как реализовать этот же код но без вайлов (желательно кодом)

Comment: Чем вам while не нравится?

Comment: Я тоже не понял почему преподу не нравится

Comment: Задание в чем заключается?

Comment: сделать этот же код но не используя вайл, то есть пользователь должен ввести свое имя если не вводит выходит алерт что это поле не может быть пустым

Comment: Нужно реализовать рекурсивную функцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете по рекурсии вызывать функцию, пока условие не будет выполнено. Если Вам действительно по какой-то причине требуется избавиться от `while`. Но оба варианта вполне себе легитимные.

```js
let carSecSpecif = '';

const getName = () => {
  carSecSpecif = prompt('Введите имя первого человека')
  if (!carSecSpecif) {
    alert('Это поле не может быть пустым')
    getName()
  }
}

getName()
```